# pairwise comparisons within a dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, cosine-similarity

My data is 18 vectors each with upto 200 numbers but some with 5 or other numbers.. organised as:

```
[2, 3, 35, 63, 64, 298, 523, 624, 625, 626, 823, 824]
[2, 752, 753, 808, 843]
[2, 752, 753, 843]
[2, 752, 753, 808, 843]
[3, 36, 37, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, ...]
```

I would like to find the pair that is the most similar in this group of lists. The numbers themselves are not important, they may as well be strings - a 2 in one list and a 3 in another list are not comparable.

I am looking if the variables are the same. for example, the second list is exactly the same as the 4th list but only  1 variable different from list 3.

Additionally it would be nice to also find the most similar triplet or n that are the most similar, but pairwise is the first and most important task.

I hope i have layed out this problem clear enough but i am very happy to supply any more information that anyone might need!

I have a feeling it involves numpy or scipy norm/cosine calculations, but i cant quite work out how to do it, or if this is the best method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give a more precise definition of what you mean by "similar"? Do you mean pairs of numbers with the smallest difference? In your three example lists, what would be the "most similar" pair? Which is more similar, (63,64) from the first list or (752,753) from the second?

Comment: I updated it with an example

Comment: Is the position important, or are you interest in only if the items in each list have a copy in another list?

Comment: Kezzos, the position is not important. the values are unique and will only occur once and therefore position is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools` to generate your pairwise comparisons. If you just want the items which are shared between two lists you can use a `set` intersection. Using your example:

```python
import itertools

a = [2, 3, 35, 63, 64, 298, 523, 624, 625, 626, 823, 824]
b = [2, 752, 753, 808, 843]
c = [2, 752, 753, 843]
d = [2, 752, 753, 808, 843]
e = [3, 36, 37, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]

data = [a, b, c, d, e]

def number_same(a, b):
    # Find the items which are the same
    return set(a).intersection(set(b))

for i in itertools.permutations([i for i in range(len(data) - 1)], r=2):
    print "Indexes: ", i, len(number_same(data[i[0]], data[i[1]]))

>>>Indexes  (0, 1) 1
Indexes  (0, 2) 1
Indexes  (0, 3) 1
Indexes  (1, 0) 1
Indexes  (1, 2) 4
Indexes  (1, 3) 5  ... etc
```

This will give the number of items which are shared between two lists, you could maybe use this information to define which two lists are the best pair...

Comment: i get the error TypeError: object of type 'itertools.islice' has no len()

Comment: Could you also explain what is going on in the core of the script?

Comment: I am on 2.7, does that make a difference?

Comment: The permutations generates pairs of indexes, the indexes are used to fetch different sublists from the main data list

Comment: How would i now get this out into a spreadsheet, i am having trouble separating the variables names as they seem to be tied to "i"