# How find pairwise disjoint sets of a given dataset?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a data set consisting lists of varying lengths similar to this example : [pairwise comparisons within a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128515/pairwise-comparisons-within-a-dataset)

more context : [Given a set of update requests for a table how can I use this to split requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134463/given-a-set-of-update-requests-for-a-table-how-can-i-use-this-to-split-requests)

I'm looking to output a the set of pairwise disjoint sets such that if you union all the fields they are unique (I'm unsure, if the term pairwise disjoint for this output is correct).

```
for example input,
[1,2,5,6,8]
[4,5,7,9]
[10,11]
[23,45]

can give an output of 
[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9] -- is combined as 5 is common.
[10,11]
[23,45]
```

1. Ideally I'm splitting the given datasets, to unique sets which are disjoint.
2. My list size can be ~150.
3. Total dataset can be of size ~700.

I tried this : [Find in python combinations of mutually exclusive sets from a list's elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572559/find-in-python-combinations-of-mutually-exclusive-sets-from-a-lists-elements) but it does not do what i need.

Comment: Was 11 supposed to turn into 15? And you mean that any input sets that share elements should be combined?

Comment: Adding restrictions that explain why {{1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {15}, {23}, {45}} and {{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 23, 45}} are wrong would probably help make the question clearer. Also which metric you’re trying to optimize for, if there are multiple correct solutions.

Comment: @Ry- I ideally want to split given data into multiple sets, in such a way that no value is repeated. What I'm trying to optimize for is the set size, like if there is a way to split into 3 equal sized sets with no common elements among them then thats my ideal solution. For example, Consider the input data like usages of a particular item, first person used [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9], 2nd used [10,15] etc. From this usage pattern, I want to determine a way to split items, in such a way that there is no intersection (a person using a thing goes only to one bucket and never intersect with another).

Comment: I don’t understand where people come into it. Can you explain why the solutions I mentioned in the last comment don’t fit, or why putting them all into one set and dividing it into 3 equal parts doesn’t work? And again, was it intentional for [10,11] to turn into [10,15]?

Comment: Sorry, That was a typo on my part with [10,15], I've edited this now. The people thing is just an example to explain, to compare these input set values to usage patterns on items, by people. Your solution, has repetitions across sets, like 1 in found in 2 sets, I want in such a way that, if you take intersection of all output sets it will be empty.

Comment: I asked about two *different* solutions, to be clear. They don’t have repetitions. {{1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {*11*}, {23}, {45}} all distinct is one. {{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, *11*, 15, 23, 45}} all distinct is the other.